# scroll value not get in content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am  try to get scroll height, scroll top of content page div in this way

but result is undefined

```
var scrolltop = $('#DivUserWebDetail').attr('scrollTop');
//scroll height 
var scrollheight = $('#DivUserWebDetail').attr('scrollHeight');
//client height 
var windowheight = $('#DivUserWebDetail').attr('clientHeight');
```

"DivUserWebDetail" is my content page divwhich height 400px and overflow hidden

please give any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `.prop('scrollHeight');`  not   `.attr('scrollHeight');`